# How to login to Facebook Developer site using Facebook for workplace account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I have created a facebook for workplace account for my organization. I have a System Administrator role.

I am working to fetch contents (post, comments and etc) of all users of my organization employees using the Facebook Graph API.

I tried to login to developers.facebook.com to test the Grpah API but could not able to login.

Is there a separate URL for workplace for developer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not that I know of. You need to use your own, personal account for app development on the FB platform.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CBroe.

We have to use the login to the Graph API tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer using your normal facebook developer account and there we have to use the access token of workplace to test the workplace api.

Comment: Have you implemented or tested this? Prakash

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Sorry, it was a long back I asked this. But as far as I remember and like mentioned in the comment above, we have to login to graph explorer using normal facebook developer account and then we just need to pass workplace token to test api.